# Adding brushes for sculpting in 2.83, missing config folder

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

So I was able to append the brushes and use them in the sculpt mode. However, some of them didnt work properly, so I looked up how to install them properly. From the zip file im supposed to put it in the folder, config. Which I just can't find:

I got my pathway:

[image: my pathway]

I'm not sure finding this folder would help either way.
So the actual issue with the brushes is that they keep drawing squares where they are supposed to draw cracks.

[image: The result of the brush]

Answer (score 0):

The brushes worked fine as soon as I moved them to the Blender 2.83 Folder you see above.

I think it has to do with administrative authority required to move them there.